# Error with loading dozer mapping file in apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, jbossfuse, dozer

I'm using the dozer component in Camel Jboss Fuse 6.3.0.redhat-187. I have a problem when I load dozer mapping file.

I got this error message in Jboss Fuse interface logs.

```
FILE-PROCESSOR | test.txt | org.dozer.MappingException: Unable to locate dozer mapping file [mapping.xml] in the classpath !
```

I had tried everthing to solve this problem.

Comment: Where is the file located? Could you share the route with us?

Comment: It's located under src/main/resources folder

Answer (score 0):

I think that this might be https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer/issues/22 you are seeing.  I think the suggestion is that if you have multiple dozer mapping files, you should include them in the same bundle to avoid the classloading problem referenced above.